# Cannot resize div at 100% height

Tags: html, css

I need make tall the red div at 100% height of the view port.

My current code does not work as expected (please scroll the div), as you can see it does not scale properly.

- How to fix it?
- What is the problem?

```css
#root {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="a">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The red element is 100% the height of the viewport - since the viewport is the size of the visible screen.

Comment: ok, how to increase its size?

Comment: I can also change the markup

Comment: write it in pixels like `width:1000px`

Comment: Since you have more content inside of  div a it stretches, div b stays the same. Either make them equal or take it out. Another way is to account for how much you stretch div a in pixels or ems and apply that to the height of div b

Comment: Or you can make `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Your red div is already take 100% of the screen

but if You mean by 100% to = 2 blue div try this:

You should calculate The blue tall and give it to the red

```css
#root {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  widht: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

#a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200vh;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="a">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're allowed to used jQuery you can just do this:

```
$("#root").on("scroll", function() {
    $("#b").css("top", $("#root")[0].scrollTop + "px");
});
```

to keep your div always in sight.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w3u8np46/10/